# Encabezado estático se descuadra cuando el texto es grande

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap-4

Quiero hacer que los encabezados sean estáticos con Bootstrap en una tabla El código funciona bien pero cuando en un campo el texto es grande, se descuadra toda la tabla. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```css
.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 230px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}

.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead>tr>th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<br>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Tabla con Scroll, header</h1>
  <br>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table table-fixed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Cta. Contable</th>
            <th>Proveedor</th>
            <th>D2</th>
            <th>D3</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Valor 1.2</td>
            <td>Valor 1.3</td>
            <td>Valor 1.4</td>
            <td>Valor 1.5</td>
            <td>Valor 1.6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Valor 1.2</td>
            <td>Valor 1.3</td>
            <td>Valor 1.4</td>
            <td>Valor 1.5</td>
            <td>Valor 1.6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Valor 1.2</td>
            <td>Valor 1.3</td>
            <td>Valor 1.4</td>
            <td>Valor 1.5</td>
            <td>Valor 1.6</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Valor 1.2</td>
            <td>Valor 1.3</td>
            <td>Valor 1.4</td>
            <td>Valor 1.5</td>
            <td>Valor 1.6</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Éste es el primer resultado:

[image: este es el primer resultado]

Y ese es el problema:

[image: ese es el problema]

Comment: Hola kevin, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: depende de como quieras que se vea el texto (agrandar alto de fila, texto recortado, max una linea, 2 lineas etc..)

Comment: Quiero que cuando un texto sea largo de cualquier celda, automaticamente todas las demás celdas de esa fila tengas el mismo alto. 
Lo he intentado de varias formas pero no logro encontrar una solución

Comment: El problema es la tabla misma, las tablas están diseñadas para funcionar de manera estática y no responsiva, el problema es que tu vista es muy corta para abarcar tantas columnas, en ese caso te recomiendo reemplazar la tabla por otra cosa, por ejemplo por encabezados con datos desplegables o utilizar menos columnas. Le he sacado el `table-fixed` y me funciona bien.